# node js, express js, mongodb, mongoose, i'm not able to push my record in existing collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my controller

```
export const updateMovie = async (request, response) => {
// console.log(request.body);
// console.log(request.files);

// process.exit();

try {
    const document = await movieSchm.findById(request.params.id);

    // some intialized objects

    const subtitles_language_files = new Object();
    const sourceUrl_language_files = new Object();

    // assigning files name here

    const files = request.files;
    const namedFiles = {};

    // check if the document exists
    if (!document) {
        throw new Error("Invalid Id");
    }

    if (Object.values(request.files).length !== 0) {
        const srtFile = request.files.filter((file) =>
            file.originalname.endsWith(".srt")
        );

        const mp4Files = request.files.filter((file) =>
            file.originalname.endsWith(".mp4")
        );

        const jpegFiles = request.files.filter((file) =>
            file.originalname.endsWith(".jpeg")
        );

        const jpgFiles = request.files.filter((file) =>
            file.originalname.endsWith(".jpg")
        );

        if (
            !srtFile.length &&
            !mp4Files.length &&
            !jpegFiles.length &&
            !jpgFiles.length
        ) {
            const error = new Error("No file provided!");
            error.statusCode = 422;
            error.message = "Unknown file format";
            return next(error);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const file = files[i];
            const fieldName = file.fieldname;

            namedFiles[fieldName] = {
                originalname: file.originalname,
                encoding: file.encoding,
                mimetype: file.mimetype,
                destination: file.destination,
                filename: file.filename,
                path: file.path,
                size: file.size,
            };
        }

        const srtFiles = request.files.filter((file) =>
            file.originalname.endsWith(".srt")
        );
        const totalsrt = srtFiles.length;

        if (totalsrt > 0) {
            for (let index = 0; index < totalsrt; index++) {

                subtitles_language_files[`language${index}`] =
                    request.body[`sub_language${index}`];
                subtitles_language_files[`subtitle_url${index}`] = srtFiles[index];
            }
        }

        const vidFiles = request.files.filter((file) =>
            file.originalname.endsWith(".mp4")
        );
        const totalmp4 = vidFiles.length;
        if (totalmp4 > 0) {
            for (let index = 0; index < totalmp4; index++) {
                const sourceUrl = uuidv4();

                sourceUrl_language_files[sourceUrl] = {
                    language: request.body[`language${index}`],
                    source_url: vidFiles[index],
                };
            }
        }

    }


    const update = {
        $set: {
            title: request.body.title,

            description: request.body.description,
            year: request.body.year,
            classification: request.body.classification,
            rating: request.body.rating,
            sub_lable: request.body.sub_lable,
            duration: request.body.duration,

            enable_comments: request.body.enable_comments,
            trailer: request.body.trailer,

            actors: JSON.parse(request.body.actors),

            subtitles_language_files: Object.keys(subtitles_language_files).length !== 0 ?
                subtitles_language_files :
                undefined,

            categories: request.body.categories ?
                JSON.parse(request.body.categories) :
                undefined,
            tags: request.body.tags ? request.body.tags : undefined,



            poster_img: namedFiles.poster_img ? namedFiles.poster_img : undefined,
            banner_img: namedFiles.banner_img ? namedFiles.banner_img : undefined,
        },
        $push: {
            sourceUrl_language_files: sourceUrl_language_files,
        }
    };

    // console.log(update)
    // process.exit();

    // console.log(update);
    // process.exit();

    const updatedMovie = await movieSchm.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: request.params.id
        },
        update, {
            new: true,
            upsert: false
        }
    );

    if (!updatedMovie) {
        throw new Error("Episode not found");
    }

    response.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "successfully updated",
        data: updatedMovie,
    });
} catch (error) {
    response.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: error.message
    });
}
```

};

and this is my schema

{
title: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
description: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
sub_lable: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
year: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
classification: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
rating: {
type: Number,
required: true,
min: 0,
max: 5,
default: 0,
},
duration: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},

```
tags: [{
    type: [String],
}, ],
enable_comments: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    required: true,
},
categories: [{
    type: Object,
    required: true,
}, ],
trailer: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    match: /^(https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?$/,
    message: "Invalid URL format",
},
sourceUrl_language_files: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
},

poster_img: {
    type: Array,
    require: true,
},
banner_img: {
    type: Array,
    require: true,
},
subtitles_language_files: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
},
actors: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    validate: {
        validator: function(value) {
            // Check if the value is an object with multiple keys and values
            if (typeof value !== "object" || Object.keys(value).length === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            // Check if all keys are numbers and values are strings without special characters
            for (const key in value) {
                if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-_,&]+$/.test(key)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
        message: "myField must be an object with numeric keys and string values without special characters",
    },
},
```

}, {
timestamps: {
createdAt: "created_at",
updatedAt: "updated_at"
}
}

The issue is I'm not able to push the record for sourceUrl_language_files field. I'm passing here dynamically generated object and each value to it. I want to pass the upcoming value to there instead of replacing old one.